# I am trying to let the navbar background change when scrolled down from transparent to forestgreen using Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the page is scrolled down the navbar stays transparent as set by default. I have tried using jquery but no success.
This is the navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <%= link_to "PEAK YOUR HIGH", root_path, class: "navbar-brand", id: "logo" %>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
          <%= link_to "Map", '#', class: "nav-link" %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Trips", '#', class: "nav-link" %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href='#'> Action2 </a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to "Forum", '#', class: "nav-link" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

This is my jquery in app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){$('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);});
```

And this are the color set up in custom.css.scss file :

```
 .bg-light{
    background: transparent !important;
}

.bg-light.scrolled {
    background: forestgreen !important;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/styling-based-on-scroll-position/

Comment: did you see in the html inspector if the class `scrolled` is added or not.? might be just CSS issue then.

Comment: When you add a event handler on events like scroll or resize they will fire over and over which is performance problem. Use a debouncer like in the tutorial linked by @tgmerritt